# "FILESTREAM Access Level" stuck at disabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

SQL Server "FILESTREAM Access Level" is stuck at disabled. I have checked all ways by SSMS and queries.

After restart, also my configured value is Full Access but Running value is disabled:

[image: After restart, also my configured value is Full Access but Running value is disabled]

Windows 10 Enterprise v1703 Build 15063 Redstone 2

Answer (score 3):

After lots of efforts finally I found the solution to my problem:
1- Computer Management -> Services and Applications -> SQL Server Service -> SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER{Your Instance Name})
2- Change User to an administrator user in Log On tab
3- Enable check check boxes considering your goal from FILESTREAM tab

Comment: So, Windows Update caused SQL to require Admin account to present FILESTREAM access...

Answer (score 0):

This [Windows 10 Creators Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016871/windows-10-update-kb4016871) intoduced a problem with Filestream when the SQL Server service account is a non-admin. A fix has since been released. You should no longer need to run SQL Server as an admin if you are current with Windows 10 updates.

Comment: Fix? I have this issue too.
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4517790) - 15.0.2070.41 (X64)   Oct 28 2019 19:56:59   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home Single Language 10.0 <X64> (Build 18363: ) 
SQL Server Management Studio      15.0.18330.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)      16.100.37971.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      15.0.19040.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.18362.1
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      10.0.18363

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN Social](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/90fc0ed4-a28f-4656-9f93-516ffc72fe31/filestream-service-cannot-be-started-after-reboot?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

My experience is that the SQL Management Studio does not facilitate enabling FILESTREAM.
This is done on the SQL Server Configuration Manager, on the instance... 
[image: Tab on SQL Server instance in Configuration Manager]

Then, when creating a FILESTREAM folder, its accessed by 
\\[machine name]\[SQL Instance]\[TableName]